# How to get rid of the green Javascript highlighting in NetBeans?

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I know this isn't a direct programming question, but who else besides programmers use Netbeans, so I figured this would be the best place to ask and actually get an answer. So, please don't close the question.

So what I want to get rid of, is the light green highlighting that happens to all Javascript in Netbeans:

http://tinypic.com/r/2q8okxu/7

Answer (score 4):

Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Syntax  [Category : keywords] Select Foreground: black.

Added:
Javascript embedded in html / php
Syntax [ Language : HTML ] Select "Javascript Embedded in HTML" Select Background: inherited.

Comment: by the way I'm not talking about keyword colors for "var". "function", etc. but the main blue background color appearing behind all js code

Answer (score 0):

Look for a "reserved keywords" or "keywords" setting in NetBean's syntax highlighting options.

Answer (score 0):

After doing Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors->Syntax [Language:HTML] [Category:Javascript Embedded in HTML] Select Background:Inherited; please be sure to close the file you are observing and then re-open it (to refresh the setting).